При других – дополнение или обстоятельство?

При других она была весела, общительна.

Каким членом предложения является сочетание предлога с определительным местоимением "другие"?
Этот вопрос тоже из теста, и опять я не согласен с ответом.

Лучше бы за вопрос проголосовали участники наши...

@Sharon, спасибо за правку!

@АлександрСтрелец, что не так? Предложите свой вариант .

Русский родной. А пишу я быстро, вот и опечатки.

Вот теперь можно и плюс поставить. Я удалил все свои комменты, можете сделать это и вы.

Пусть еще голосуют, я недовольна результатом.  Надо еще 2 голоса)  Тогда удалю.

При других она была весела, общительна.

Это обстоятельство, которое обозначает внешние обстоятельства проявления признака, в данном случае обстановку, в которой проявляется признак. Эту обстановку задает присутствие других людей. Можно задать обобщенный вопрос: в каких случаях? при каких обстоятельствах?

Значение предлога ПРИ по словарю:
4. Указывает на лицо, в присутствии которого что-л. 
происходит. Осрамиться при всём честном народе. Подавать 
деньги при свидетелях. Браниться при гостях. Не говорите 
лишнего при посторонних. * Не пой, красавица, при мне Ты 
песен Грузии печальной... (Пушкин). 


Почему не дополнение? Ведь можно задать вопрос: при ком? Но это общий падежный вопрос для предлога ПРИ, а вот значение у предлога должно быть, к примеру, такое:

При нем были документы.
5. Указывает на лицо, имеющее в наличии что-л.; у. Оружия 
при нём не было. Документы всегда при мне. Деньги при тебе? 
Ключи от машины держит при себе. 

ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Дополнение — это второстепенный член предложения, называющий лицо, предмет или явление, на который распространяется действие или по отношению к которому проявляется признак.
Обстоятельство — это второстепенный член предложения, который относится к слову со значением действия или признака и
обозначает качественные и количественные характеристики этого
действия или признака (способ осуществления действия, степень
интенсивности действия или проявления признака), а также различные внешние обстоятельства осуществления действия (время, причину, условие и т.д.).

Да, кстати, в ответах дополнение.

Я так и поняла - простое решение, задается падежный вопрос.  И отличить обстоятельство от дополнения не всегда легко. Я на слух определила, что обстоятельство,  ну и по определению из учебника. Но вот доказывать пришлось по словарю.

И это все те же аттестационные тесты для учителей. Постоянно там ошибки.

Дополнение, при ком, при чем — при других.

Дополнение – это второстепенный член предложения, который обозначает предмет:
объект, на который распространяется действие;

Пишу письмо; слушаю музыку.
объект – адресат действия;

Пишу другу.
объект – орудие или средство действия;

Пишу ручкой.
объект, на который распространяется состояние;

Мне грустно.
объект сравнения и др.

Быстрее меня.

Дополнение отвечает на вопросы косвенных падежей.
